# visreg plot binomial distribution

Tags: r, plot, glm

I'm studying the effect of different predictors (dummy, categorical and continuos variables) on presence of birds, obtained from bird counts at-sea. To do that I used a `glmmadmb` function and `binomial` family.

I've plotted the relationship between response variable and predictors in order to asses the model fit and the marginal effect of each predictor. To draw the graphs I used `visreg` function, specifying the transformation of the vertical axis:

```
visreg(modelo.bn7, type="conditional", scale="response", ylab= "Bird Presence")
```

The output graphs showed a confident bands very wide when I used the original scale of the response variable (covering the whole vertical axis). In case of graphs without transformation, confident bands were shorter but they had the same extension in the different levels of dummy variables. Does anyone know how the confidents bands are calculated in binomial distributions? Could it reflect that I have a problem in the estimated coefficients or in the model fit?

Answer (score 0):

The confidence bands are calculated using p-values for binomial distribution... For detailed explanation you can ask on stats.stackexchange.com. If the bands are very wide (and the interpretation of 'wide' is subjective and mostly based on what is your goal) then it shows that your estimates may not be very accurate. High p-values usually are due to small or insufficient number of observations used for building the model. If the number of observations are large, then it does indicate a poor fit.